# Manifest's license tag for proprietary ROS packages

Tags: ros, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `license` tag of package manifests (`package.xml`) seems to be mandatory. What should I set it to for a proprietary package that won't be open-sourced? (Assuming I'm not including or linking against "infectious" open-source licenses of course.)

I've been writing the following and then adding copyright headers to the actual source code.

```
<license>Proprietary</license>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226951/manifest%27s-license-tag-for-proprietary-ros-packages/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-17**:
I use `Proprietary` for the license on my private packages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same here. REP-140 gives examples of OSS licenses ([here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#license-multiple-but-at-least-one)), anything else is up to you.

What you shouldn't do though, is paste your license *text* in the `license` tag. I've seen ppl do that, and it's not what the tag is for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-06-22**:
Related, now license *text* file can be specified in `package.xml` format=3 after [this PR](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/157).